# Find cell with repeated values

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2010

I need to find different `Product Brand`s (Column D) on the basis of concatenation of Column A (`Region`) and Column B (`Product`). Column C contains the concatenation of Col A and Col B.

The issue is values in Column A and Column B can be repeated, so I can't use =VLOOKUP to find the distinct `Product Brand`s.

My input looks like this:-

```
Region      Product     Concat       Product Brand    

R1          P3          R1P3         PB1
R2          P2          R2P2         PB1
R3          P3          R3P3         PB1
R4          P4          R4P4         PB1
R5          P5          R5P5         PB1
R1          P1          R1P1         PB2
R1          P1          R1P1         PB3
R1          P2          R1P2         PB4
R1          P1          R1P1         PB5
R1          P1          R1P1         PB6
R1          P1          R1P1         PB7
R2          P1          R2P1         PB2
```

If I select Region 1 (R1) and Product P1 (in another application) I should be able to show all the product brands with that combination in different cells. My result set should look like (say in Cols E & F):

```
R1P1      PB2
R1P1      PB3
R1P1      PB4
R1P1      PB5
R1P1      PB6
R1P1      PB7
```

I need a pure Excel formula solution, no pivot, no VB and no other filter options.

Any help would be really appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming a layout as below:

[image: SO19675938 example]

then in F1 and copied down to suit:

```
=IFERROR(INDEX($D$1:$D$14,SMALL(IF($C$1:$C$14=E$1,ROW($D$1:$D$14),9.99E+207),ROW())),"")
```

(entered with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>) and in E2 and copied down to suit:

```
=IF(F2<>"",E1,"")
```

should I think meet your requirements provided your `Concat` value is entered in E1, though you may wish to extend the row references.

Answer (score 0):

Heres a solution using array formulas:
Suppose we are to use your sample data located in `A1:D13`.

Select `E1:E13` and in formula bar write this:

```
=IF(C1:C13=G1&H1,C1:C13,"")
```

The press CTRL+SHIFT+ENTER.

Similarly, in `F1:F13` write this:

```
=IF(C1:C13=G1&H1,D1:D13,"")
```

Note: Value Displayed is depending on your `G1` and `H1` input.
If it is blank, you'll see blank on `E1:F13`.
If you input R1 and P1 in `G1` and `H1` respectively, `E1:F13` will display all R1P1 and their corresponding B(x).
But you have blanks in between. Almost there.

Now, select `G2` and enter this formula:

```
=INDEX(E$2:E$13, MATCH(LARGE(COUNTIF(E$2:E$13, "<"&E$2:E$13), ROW(1:1)), COUNTIF(E$2:E$13, "<"&E$2:E$13), 0))
```

Again, enter it as array formula (CTRL+SHIFT+ENTER).
Drag until `G13`.

Similarly, in `H2` write this formula:

```
=INDEX(F$2:F$11, MATCH(LARGE(COUNTIF(F$2:F$11, "<"&F$2:F$11), ROW(1:1)), COUNTIF(F$2:F$11, "<"&F$2:F$11), 0))
```

Again, enter it as array formula (CTRL+SHIFT+ENTER).
Drag until `H13`.

Now you can see the R1P1 and all the B(x) without blank in between.
This is based on this [article](http://www.get-digital-help.com/2009/03/27/sorting-text-cells-using-array-formula/) which you might want to read.

Comment: It worked!!! I just corrected the range in the last formula **(F$2:F$13)** instead of _(F$2:F$11)_.

Comment: glad it did. not as good as pnuts' though. hehe Explore array formula and you'll be able to do a lot with it.

Comment: Yes, He did in a single step. But I got to learn two different way to solve the issue. There could be another way without using array. I did 5 years back but unfortunately I don't remember how I did it. I did for a small set of data with some numbers involved, so did some ranking and other manipulation :)